# Accessing a widget from outside of its class?

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt Creator, I have a couple of widgets declared like so:

Header File:

```
    class MapViewer : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MapViewer(QGraphicsScene *scene, QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MapViewer();

public slots:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

};

// Declaration for the map editor window.
class MapEditor : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MapEditor(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MapEditor();

public:
    QLayout *editorLayout;
    QPushButton *btn;
    QGraphicsScene *mapScene;
    MapViewer *mapView;

private:
    Ui::MapEditor *ui;
};
```

CPP File:

```
  MapEditor::MapEditor(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MapEditor)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowTitle("2DXY :: Map Editor");
    this->setGeometry(10,10,1170,750);
    editorLayout = new QVBoxLayout; // Create a new layout
    this->setLayout(editorLayout); // Set the widget's layout to our newly created layout.

    mapScene = new QGraphicsScene(); // Create a new graphics scene to draw upon.

    mapView = new MapViewer(mapScene,this); // Create a new graphics view to display our scene - set its parent to 'this' so that it doesn't open in a new window.
    mapView->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    mapView->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    mapView->setGeometry(20,20,1178,546); // Width first, then height.
```

AND:

```
void MapViewer::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    // Show an empty message box, just to check that the event handler works!
    QMessageBox *notification = new QMessageBox();
    notification->show();
    notification->exec();
    // Some how access the same QGraphicsScene and View (mapScene, mapView) as above, so
    // I can update their contents on the open form / window.

}
```

And as you can see, I wish to access the Graphics Scene again to update it, then redraw it (or whatever). But I'm not able to access the graphics scene at all, despite a few hours of trial and error with declaring widgets in different ways.

I know that the listener itself works, because if it's set to open a new message box, or output to the debug window, then it works, it's just that I can't access the widgets I've already defined.

I feel that there is a (relatively) easy solution to this problem, and that I'm just missing something obvious.

Comment: Just make them member variables of the class and provide getter methods...

Comment: @cmannett85 - Could you explain this in more detail / provide an example? (I'm quite new to C++!) Thanks!

Comment: Bret Kuhns did a good job of that.  However I must stress that this is _not_ the way to learn C++! Qt uses some unusual/unavailable paradigms compared to   'normal' C++, so learn the language first and then the framework.

Comment: Thanks - I've learnt some more about the structure that C++ uses, and I think I've made my code 'cleaner', however, using Bret's code I've only been able to access the widget is by making a new instance of it, whereas I want to update an existing instance of the widget. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do want `MapEditor` to only contain one `QGraphicsScene`?  So the _same_ `QGraphicsScene` is passed into a newly built `MapRender` each time `MapEditor::addWidget()` is called?

Comment: @cmannett85 I've updated the code in my post to reflect the changes I've made. Essentially, I want it so that when the user clicks on the graphics view, a box (or whatever) is drawn on that graphicsview - when they click again, another box is added to the graphics view. So on and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void MapViewer::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    // Show an empty message box, just to check that the event handler works!
    QMessageBox *notification = new QMessageBox();
    notification->show();
    notification->exec();

    //  To add something whenever the user clicks, you don't need the view,
    //  just the scene.
    scene()->addItem( new MyItem() );
}
```

Remember `MapViewer` derives from `QGraphicsView` and the view must know about the scene it belongs to - so it has a `scene()` method to return it, which you inherited.

Comment: Ah, I see! That works great! Thanks a lot for your patience and understanding!

Answer (score 1):

You passed the `QGraphicsScene` to your `MapRender` object's constructor. What do you do with the scene within its constructor? Ideally, you should be storing it as a data member of `MapRender`. For example:

```
class MapRender {
public:
    MapRender(QGraphicsScene* scene)
      : scene_(scene)
    {
    }

public slots:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

private:
    QGraphicsScene* scene_;
}
```

Now in your implementation of `mousePressEvent`, you can access to the scene member:

```
void MapRender::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    int CursorX = event->globalX();
    int CursorY = event->globalY();

    QGraphicsRectItem *clickedBox = new QGraphicsRectItem(40,40,32,32);
    clickedBox->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::blue));

    scene_->addItem(clickedBox);
}
```

Keep in mind you should ideally be putting the implementation of the constructor in your cpp file, but my example does it in the declaration for brevity.

Comment: I can now access the QGraphicsScene fine from the mousePressEvent handler, however how would I access it from the MapEditor::addWidget() method, for example, to draw on it?

`scene_->addLine(...);`

Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: Well, you constructed the scene in `MapEditor::addWidget()` so you can access it normally with `scene->addLine(...);` (after you `new` it in your example). Passing a pointer to an object to a function/constructor does not invalidate the pointer within your current scope.